# Project facet jst.webfragment has not been defined after create a web project from svn repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, project, facet

i am new to svn. i have a dynamic web project developed in eclipse. the server is apache tomcat 6. it worked fine .on my local machine as a development environment.
   today, i import this project into a svn repository.  below is how i did it
    1. i upload the whole project folder into the linux server
    2. i removed the class files
    3. i import the reset into a branch
    4. i create a new eclipse workspace
    5  i create a new project from svn repository.
    6. everything is ok but i got only one error, showing below

```
Project facet jst.webfragment has not been defined. It is used in plugin org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.

 what's project facet?  do I need to create one? what's the right step to add a eclipse web project into a svn repository
```

Thanks
Heng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message indicates a bug in your Eclipse install and is not related to your project or SVN operation. Please report this issue on Eclipse WebTools forum. Make sure to describe your Eclipse install... what version it is... what distro you started with... what you added... etc.

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=88&

Comment: ok, but how to solve my problem, i use gallio. so upgrade to helios?

Comment: right. galileo has no support for jst.webfragment. perhaps you somehow managed to install some helios-specific plugins.